# Insufficient space allocated to copy array contents

Tags: arrays, swift

I am building up some code to request multiple information from a database in order to have a time table in my front end incl. multiple DB requests.

The problem is that with one particular request where . am using swiftKuery and DispatchGroups i receive ooccasionally but not always an error message in my XCode. This can not be reconstructed by different request but just sometimes happens.

here is a snippet of my code.

```
var profWorkDaysBreak = [time_workbreaks]()
let groupServiceWorkDayBreaks = DispatchGroup()

...

  ///WorkdaysBreakENTER AsyncCall
        //UnreliableCode ?
        profWorkDays.forEach {workDay in
            groupServiceWorkDayBreaks.enter()
            time_workbreaks.getAll(weekDayId: workDay.id) { results, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
                if let results = results {
                    profWorkDaysBreak.append(contentsOf: results) // The error happens here !
                }
                groupServiceWorkDayBreaks.leave()
            }
        } 

...

groupServiceWorkDayBreaks.wait()
```

The results and profWorkDaysBreak variables are the same just sometimes i receive the message:

Fatal error: Insufficient space allocated to copy array contents
This leads to a stop of the execution.

I assume, that maybe the loop might sometimes finish an earlier execution in the DispatchGroup ??? but this is the only think i have as an idea....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the only way i got my code running reliable so far..
i skipped contents of completely and just went to a forEach Loop

```
var profWorkDaysBreak = [time_workbreaks]()
let groupServiceWorkDayBreaks = DispatchGroup()

...

  ///WorkdaysBreakENTER AsyncCall
        //UnreliableCode ?
        profWorkDays.forEach {workDay in
            groupServiceWorkDayBreaks.enter()
            time_workbreaks.getAll(weekDayId: workDay.id) { results, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
                if let results = results {
                    results.forEach {profWorkDayBreak in
                        profWorkDaysBreak.append(profWorkDayBreak)
                    }
                /*
                //Alternative causes error !
                profWorkDaysBreak.append(contentsOf: results)
                */
                }
                groupServiceWorkDayBreaks.leave()
            }
        } 

...

groupServiceWorkDayBreaks.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is caused by some race conditions due to the fact that you modify the array from multiple threads. And if two threads happen to try and alter the array at the same time, you get into problems.

Make sure you serialize the access to the array, this should solve the problem. You can use a semaphore for that:

```swift
var profWorkDaysBreak = [time_workbreaks]()
let groupServiceWorkDayBreaks = DispatchGroup()
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
...


profWorkDays.forEach { workDay in
    groupServiceWorkDayBreaks.enter()
    time_workbreaks.getAll(weekDayId: workDay.id) { results, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        if let results = results {
            // acquire the lock, perform the non-thread safe operation, release the lock
            semaphore.wait()
            profWorkDaysBreak.append(contentsOf: results) // The error happens here !
            semaphore.signal()
        }
        groupServiceWorkDayBreaks.leave()
    }
}

...

groupServiceWorkDayBreaks.wait()
```

The semaphore here acts like a mutex, allowing at most one thread to operate on the array. Also I would like to emphasise the fact that the lock should be hold for the least amount of time possible, so that the other threads don't have to wait for too much.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback, but would your code not lead to be a continued execution while not waiting for the getAll (asyncCall to db) to be finished ?

Comment: OK, I updated the answer to keep the original group behaviour, using the semaphore only for locking stuff. @Bliv_Dev

Comment: I now found the time to try the semaphore solution... but for some reason i get the following error upon setting up the Semaphore let ... 'init()' is unavailable in Swift: Unavailable in Swift i could not find the root cause here

Comment: @Bliv_Dev I updated the answer, I previously missed adding the `value` parameter to the `DispatchSemaphore` initializer call.

Comment: I really can not get the semaphore method to run... it seems if you do as you suggest, the call simply never returns .. i now moved to a loop base approach this seems to be the most reliable and secure one.