# Fatal error: Insufficient space allocated to copy string contents (iOS 13) Emoji

Tags: swift, string, ios13, xcode11

After updating to Xcode 11 and iOS 13 I started to get this error constantly:

> Fatal error: Insufficient space allocated to copy string contents

I managed to narrow crash-related code down to this small snippet. You can paste it in a iOS app or even in a playground and it will crash:

```
// Test. This code crashes even in a playground.
let h = 3, w = 3
// No crash without "" symbol!
let fieldStrings: [String] = ["", "3", "3", "4", "1", "2", "2", "4", "2"]
let maxLength = fieldStrings.reduce(0) { (maxLength, s) in max(maxLength, s.count) }
print(maxLength) // 1
// No crash without padding!
let paddedFieldStrings = fieldStrings.map { s in
    s.padding(toLength: maxLength, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
}
var lines = [String]()
for y in 0..<h {
    var line = ""
    for x in 0..<(w - 1) {
        // CRASH HERE! x = 0, y = 0
        line += paddedFieldStrings[x * h + y] + "  "
    }
    line += paddedFieldStrings[(w - 1) * h + y]
    lines.append(line)
}
```

The original code was responsible for printing the description of a game board. It was working nice prior to iOS 13. I noticed that two points (besides string appending itself) are essential here:

1. emoji symbol "page with curl" - U+1F4C3
2. `padding(toLength:withPad)`

The crash also repeats with other emojis.

I don't think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143558/insufficient-space-allocated-to-copy-array-contents) question is a duplicate, because my case doesn't involve any multithreading or database. So, please, don't mark.

This seems to me as a bug and I'll report it to Apple, but for now we need to find a workaround.

Swift 5.

Comment: I reported the bug to Apple and to Swift Forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround:**
As we all agree - it's a system bug. The easies workaround will be to change `maxLength` calculation replacing `s.count` with `s.utf16.count`:

```
let maxLength = fieldStrings.reduce(0) { (maxLength, s) in max(maxLength, s.utf16.count) }
```

The crash is caused by `padding(toLength:withPad:startingAt:)` when the `toLength` is less than the length of the corresponding `NSString`. `NSString.length` is implied here because the `padding()` is a part of Foundation. The `utf16.count` equals to the `length` of the corresponding `NSString`. Although the problem hides inside the `padding()` func, somehow it silently returns an invalid string and later the crash appears on `+` operation. For more, see [this discussion in Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/fatal-error-insufficient-space-allocated-to-copy-string-contents-emoji-related/29653/5?u=kelin).

Answer (score 0):

This may indeed be a bug on Apple's part.

**Some context...**

Different emoji representations have different lengths. For example, ("" as String) will have a length (or `count`) of 1 while ("" as NSString) will have a length of 2 (see [this](https://www.objc.io/blog/2017/12/19/decomposing-emoji/) link for a more detailed explanation).

Your code sets `maxLength` to 1 because the length of all the strings in your array, including the emoji, resolves to 1. However, it looks like somewhere within the implementation of `padding`, the length of the emoji is resolving to 2. So, `padding` is returning `nil` when you pass an emoji and a `maxLength` of 1.

Here is some example code to help explain:

```
("" as String).count // `count` is 1
("" as NSString).length // `length` is 2

"".padding(toLength: 1, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0) // returns nil
"".padding(toLength: 2, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0) // returns ""
"".padding(toLength: 3, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0) // return " "
```

Again, this is a bit suspicious and does seem like a bug on Apple's part.

In the meantime, calculating `maxLength` using `max(maxLength, (s as NSString).length))` or even simply ensuring that `maxLength` is greater than 1 for any array that contains an emoji should fix the crash.

Comment: Sorry, are we missing something? Because `padding(toLength:withPad:)` can't return nil according to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/3126769-padding). Otherwise `paddedFieldStrings` array would have type `[String?]` and I would get a compiler error later. Anyway, thanks for introducing new info about string lengths.

Comment: Wow, when I run `print("".padding(toLength: 1, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0))` in the playground, I get really fat exception.